# on what fundamental force is a black hole based on?

Tags: astronomy

what fundalmentel force does a black hole based on?

It seems people is very unfamilar with black holes.

I will take a guess, is it electromantic force? please explain.

Comment: Look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole

Comment: I think gravity is the inward force but what is the outward force that keeps it from collapsing to a singularity? (some theories say that the singularity does not exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is in this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) article:

> A black hole is a region of spacetime where gravity prevents anything, including light, from escaping.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) The theory of general relativity predicts that a sufficiently compact mass will deform spacetime to form a black hole .

So it is **gravity** that causes the black hole's existence.

It needs college level courses to be able to work with the physics of the situation.